# how to refresh directive data in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-structures, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I made a directive which builds a tree to see who is parent or child of whom. when I go the my page it shows the tree which i wanted but when i visit some other page in my app and then route to the page in which tree is being built it shows me a wrong tree. I am building nodes to look up with scope.$id in directive so when i first route to the page "ids" are different and when i go to some other route and then come to the same route "ids" are different that's why it is appending to the data to previous tree which has already built rather than replacing it. So i want to always reset the data whenever the user navigates to that page. How can I do this in my angularjs app?

```
return {
  restrict : 'A',
  link : function(scope, element, attrs){
           var parentScope = findScope(scope, attrs.parentModel);
           collectRelations(parentScope, attrs.parentModel, scope, 
            attrs.ngModel);


    $timeout(function(){
      if (initialized)
        return;

      buildHierarchies();
      initializeStates();

      initialized = true;
    }, 0);
  }
}
```

Comment: post your complete code here, including the views and the functions `buildHierarchies` and `initializeStates`

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… **Complete – Provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem**. See [How to create a Minimal, **Complete**, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @JohnVelasquez sorry for late but here is the plunkr https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/XArO6p I am using this directive

Comment: Could you edit your plunker to have routes

Comment: Actually this plukr is not mine. I am just using the same concept as shown is this plunkr